# str_replace HTML with PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string of HTML that I want to dynamically replace with PHP variables from a $_POST.

Here is my string:

```
$message = '<html><body><font face="Arial, Helvetica" size=2><strong>Name:</strong> {$first} {$last}<br/><br/>';
```

Here is my PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        $$key = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(ucfirst(strtolower($_POST[$key]))));
        $text = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $message);
        //echo $text;
    }
```

But my str_replace is not working right.  I've tried doing the string like this:

```
 $message = '<html><body><font face="Arial, Helvetica" size=2><strong>Name:</strong> {' . $first .'} {' . $last . '}<br/><br/>';
```

But that doesn't work either.  I've tried numerous other combinations and none of them seem to work.  Some help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `...(ucfirst(strtolower($_POST[$key]))));` can be turned into a more convenient `(ucfirst(strtolower($value))));`

Comment: Why are you running `mysql_real_escape_string` on it?  In short, don't...

Comment: what does _POST contain? Try running var_dump($_POST);

Comment: It's going into a DB.  Shouldn't I escape it?

Comment: @shummel7845: Yes you should, but right before it goes into the database.  Escape the whole thing, not just parts of it (otherwise it could get confusing or open up issues since you're modifying it after it's been escaped)...

Comment: I did a var_dump on the $_POST and there were values for the variables.  Other thoughts?

Comment: A lot of what you're doing is considered highly dangerous and wide open to exploit. What is the program you are writing for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things I don't understand from the following line:

```
$$key = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(ucfirst(strtolower($_POST[$key]))));
```

- Why do you use variables variables? `$$key`
- Why do you sanitize `$_POST[$key]` when you have access to `$value`?
- Why do you use `mysql_real_escape_string` to "escape" HTML?

I think it's all unnecessary.

One of the reasons it may not work is because you are saving the modified `$message` into `$text`, instead of saving it back into `$message` to ensure that all keys will eventually be replaced. Also, I you forgot the literal `$` in the pattern, it should have been:

```
$text = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $value, $message);
______________________^
```

Here's how I would do it:

```
$_POST = array('first'=>'foo', 'last'=>'bar');

$dbData = array(); // don't forget to initialize your array
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $sanitizedValue = strip_tags(ucfirst(strtolower($value)));
    $message = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $sanitizedValue, $message);

    // save the mysql-sanitized values to an array for future use
    $dbData[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($sanitizedValue);
}

echo $message;
// outputs 
//    <html><body><font face="Arial, Helvetica" size=2><strong>Name:</strong> Foo Bar<br/><br/>';
```

I actually tested it and it works.

Comment: Thanks netcoder.  I'm kind of new, so I appreciate the help.  How do access those variables in the loop so I can insert them into the DB?  That's why I did the dynamic variable assignment, so I could have a static sql query lower down in the code.

Comment: Use an array, see my update (`$dbData`). The reason why you should use an array is because it is a data structure made specifically for that kind of task (and way more). It also prevents one from injecting variables in your code, because using `$$key` in a `foreach $_POST` actually somewhat mimics [register_globals](http://php.net/register_globals), which is indeed very bad.

Comment: THANKS NETCODER!  That's brilliant.

Comment: Is there a dynamic way using your example to generate an sql query?

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your `$text` variable on every loop with the str_replace on `$message`.

Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    $message = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $value, $message);
}
```